# save variables in a combined matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

Please excuse my naive question, the answer is probably pretty easy.
I have a matrix with 24 rows and 200 columns.

I want to store each column in a new matrix with 6 rows and 4 columns.
My data looks like this (first two of 200 columns):

```
    fin[,1:2]
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]   NA   NA
 [2,]   NA   NA
 [3,]   NA   NA
 [4,]   NA   NA
 [5,]   10    4
 [6,]   NA    3
 [7,]    4    2
 [8,]   NA    1
 [9,]    7    5
[10,]    6   NA
[11,]    1   NA
[12,]    5   NA
[13,]    8    7
[14,]   NA   NA
[15,]    2   NA
[16,]   NA   NA
[17,]   NA   NA
[18,]   NA   NA
[19,]   NA   NA
[20,]   NA   NA
[21,]    9    6
[22,]   NA   NA
[23,]    3   NA
[24,]   NA   NA
```

What I want is an output that looks like this:

```
> matrix(fin[,1], ncol = 6, byrow = FALSE)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]   NA   10    7    8   NA    9
[2,]   NA   NA    6   NA   NA   NA
[3,]   NA    4    1    2   NA    3
[4,]   NA   NA    5   NA   NA   NA
```

for each of the 200 columns and then store them in ONE matrix, 
meaning row 5 of my solution would be the first row of the matrix of column 2 and so on.

I dont need the single matrices for each column, I'm only interested in the final matrix.

Thanks in advance,
SB

Comment: Try with `split` i.e. `lapply(split(fin, col(fin)),matrix, ncol=6, byrow = FALSE)`

Comment: you guys made my day. thx!